# Is it cheaper to book excursions locally for South Africa?

Tags: budget, south-africa

For our trip to to Peru, we booked all excursions (Macchu Picchu hike, jungle tour) from home months in advance. When in Peru, we found out that it is much cheaper to book them there. Is the same true for South Africa?

Comment: To be fair, the Inca Trail hike *needs* to be booked months in advance to guarantee a spot!

Comment: @Mark Mayo Do also the other paths to Macchu Picchu such as Salkantay need to be booked months in advance ?

Comment: @Patrick - my friend booked Salkantay a week in advance. But this will differ depending on time of year, trail, and other stuff.  Just seen your other post, will add more detail when I get a chance.

Answer (score 8):

As someone who has lived there and revisited it as a tourist - yes, yes it can be. Sometimes.

The whole point of an international broker is to make it easier for you though - and you don't have to deal with problems on the ground, as you may have found in Peru, language barrier can be a pain sometimes - not as much of a problem in South Africa where most speak fluent or some English, but still.  Of course, having a middle man will always mean a mark-up.  How else do they make money!

We booked several game drives in Kruger Park through a company, and ended up being wrongly charged for one night.  And on the ground it was easier to decide what was worth doing when we could see the trucks and the situation and realise what was good and what wasn't.

However, you do run the risk of things being booked up.  Not as likely as last year during the World Cup, but still.